# Designing a makefile to compile a program configured differently

Tags: makefile, fortran, gnu-make

I have a program written in Fortran that is designed to be compiled regularly using single-precision floats (`REAL`), or with double-precision floats (using, e.g. GNU Fortran's `-fdefault-real-8`). I'd like to design a makefile to build both `myprog` and `myprog-dbl` for each of these similar programs from the same source code. Here's an abstraction of what I have so far:

`mymod.f` - shows simple floating-point error propagation

```
      MODULE mymod
       REAL :: var
      CONTAINS
      SUBROUTINE forerror(a,j)
       REAL :: a
       var=0.0
       DO i=0,j,1
           var=var+a
       END DO
       WRITE(*,*) "a=",a,"j=",j,"var=",var
      END SUBROUTINE
      END MODULE
```

`myprog.f` - main part of program

```
        PROGRAM test
         USE mymod
         CALL ForError(0.000001,10000000)
        END PROGRAM
```

`makefile` - GNU Makefile designed to build two programs: `myprog` and `myprog-dbl`

```
# Variables
FC = gfortran
LD = $(FC)
EXECS = myprog myprog-dbl
OBJECTS = myprog.o mymod.o

# Targets
all : $(EXECS)

$(EXECS) : $(OBJECTS)
    $(LD) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@ $^

# mymod must be built before prog
myprog.o : mymod.o

# Target-specific variable
myprog-dbl : FFLAGS += -fdefault-real-8

clean :
    $(RM) $(OBJECTS) *.mod

.PHONY : all clean
```

The above almost works, but not entirely. Here is the output I'm getting from the shell, first with the default target of making both programs:

```
$ make all
gfortran   -c -o mymod.o mymod.f
gfortran   -c -o myprog.o myprog.f
gfortran  -o myprog myprog.o mymod.o
gfortran  -o myprog-dbl myprog.o mymod.o
$ ./myprog
 a=   9.99999997E-07 j=    10000000 var=   9.59210873
$ ./myprog-dbl
 a=   9.99999997E-07 j=    10000000 var=   9.59210873
```

However, the `make myprog-dbl` result didn't compile the dependent objects with the appropriate flags, and it is identical to `myprog`.

The objects need to be cleaned before building the second program:

```
$ make clean
rm -f myprog.o mymod.o *.mod
$ make myprog-dbl
gfortran -fdefault-real-8  -c -o mymod.o mymod.f
gfortran -fdefault-real-8  -c -o myprog.o myprog.f
gfortran  -o myprog-dbl myprog.o mymod.o
$ ./myprog-dbl
 a=   9.9999999999999995E-007 j=    10000000 var=   10.000000999267517
```

Now it has been build with double-precision floats. How can I build the two similar programs with a single `make all` target? I'm happy to reconstruct the `makefile` (or two), but not the Fortran source.

Answer (score 2):

I would compile those two variants into different target subdirectories. Or at least place the `.mod` files there, but I would prefer to put there everything.

Just make sure you use the right flag for the module directory, which changes from compiler to compiler. Gfortran uses `-J` and `I`, Intel Fortran uses `-module` instead.

BTW `-fdefault-real-8` is ugly. Use kind constants in any new code.

Answer (score 1):

Changing the flags does not change the fact that `mymod.o` already exists if it was previously compiled with different flags.  Make simply looks at the time stamp and the declared dependencies to decide what to rebuild.

One solution would be to use different file names for modules compiled with different options, then just copy them into place for final linking.

Another would be to have `mymod.o` depend on a file which contains the flags it was built with; when this file changes, `mymod.o` needs to be rebuilt.  However, you'd probably want to avoid rewriting this file needlessly, so as not to force a recompile when it's not really necessary.  Maybe something like this:

```
flagfile.txt:
    echo "$(FFLAGS)" >tmp
    cmp tmp $@ && rm tmp || mv tmp $@
mymod.o: flagfile.txt
```

The `cmp || mv` will create a temporary file and only update `flagfile.txt` when the temporary file's contents differ from the old contents.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to rewrite the target `all` to include `clean` in between the two executable names, like

```
all: myprog clean myprog-dbl
```

The big advantage is that you change only one line of your makefile.
The only disavantage is that you will not use the variable `EXECS` that is already there, but it will do the job.